# Exit shell script using PHP exit code while looping?

Tags: php, shell, for-loop

```
#!/bin/bash
cd  /maintenance;

for (( i=1;i<1000;i++)); do
    php -q dostuff.php $i    
done
```

I use this shell script to call the `dostuff.php` script and pass the `$i` as an `agrv` to the script.  The script connects to a webservice that returns results 50 items at a time.  The `$i` value is the page number... I have no way to know how many times it needs to be called (how many pages) until I get a response code back from CURL inside that script that I test for.  I need to pass my own response code back to the shell script to have it stop looping... it will never get to 1000 iterations... it was just a quick loop I made.

If I use `exec("php -q dostuff.php $i", $output, $return_var)` how do I tell the script to keep executing and passing the incremented `$i` value until my php script exits with a response code of 0?

There has got to be a better way. Maybe a while?  Just not that good with this syntax.

I have to start at page 1 and repeat until page XXX incrementing by 1 each iteration.  When there are no more results I can test for this in the `dostuff.php` and exit(0).  What is the best way to implement this in the shell script?

Thanks!

Comment: why dont you use php for your loop? it will exits whenever you want,and n your shell,just out `php dostuff.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments, you might get way better control if you dont wrap the php script inside a bash script but instead use php-cli as the shell script (PHP is kinda shell):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    // contents of dostuff.php integrated
}
```

You might also be interested in using STDOUT, STDIN and STDERR:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

Comment: Don't know what I was thinking... of course.. just a while loop in php and then call the script from a command line... duh... thanks to both suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the return value of the script, and `break` the loop if it isn't what is expected.

Usually a script returns `0` when it ran successfully, and something else otherwise, so if I assume your script respect this condition you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd  /maintenance;

for (( i=1;i<1000;i++)); do
  php -q dostuff.php $i
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then break; fi 
done
```

On the other hand, if you want your script to return 0 if the loop *shouldn't* continue then you should do:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi
```

---

Edit: to take the comment into account to simplify the script:

If your script returns 0 when it shouldn't be called again, you instead do:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd  /maintenance;

for (( i=1;i<1000;i++)); do
  if php -q dostuff.php $i; then break; fi 
done
```

Comment: The concise and idiomatic way to write `cmd; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then x; fi` is `if cmd; then x; fi` or simply `cmd && x`

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the advice. Edited the answer accordingly